# Options for a remote-controlled bathroom exhaust fan/light?

Tags: electrical

A friend of ours has a "toilet room" with one switch that controls both the light and the exhaust fan. He'd like to be able to control the fan and the light separately, but without having to run three-conductor NM-B, possibly remove and replace drywall, etc. What can I do about this? My Google-fu is failing me. I'm handy enough that I could probably figure out a way to wire in some solenoids and remote-control them; however, I'd rather not cobble something together, especially since this wouldn't be at our own place. Thanks!

Comment: Would you rather have this controlled by two switches or one switch?

Comment: Also, what's the nameplate rating on the exhaust fan?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I'd prefer that the fan and the light be controlled separately. The switch box is 1-gang. I don't know the nameplate current; I haven't opened the fan/light fixture yet.

Comment: There are devices that can multiplex independent control of a fan and a light onto a single switch, or do you mean "uses two switches" by "controlled separately"?

Comment: I want to be able to turn on the fan but not the light, or the light but not the fan, or both, from one physical location. Could you link to examples of those devices you mentioned?

Comment: The Functional Devices [FL101](http://functionaldevices.com/pdf/datasheets/FL101.pdf) is the only one I know of that works with a standard wall switch.

Answer (score 1):

### 2 devices, 1 switch, 0 problems

If you don't mind having to operate your switch in a slightly funky way, a Functional Devices [HLF3](https://www.functionaldevices.com/products/lighting-controls/details/HAF3/) can be wired to control the fan and the light from a single wall switch.

Answer (score 0):

There is typically a wire to the light and a wire to fan all inside the box. If so, you could just get a dual switch which would allow independently control of each and save the expense/complexity of a remote switch.